# Launcher for a specific Chromium profile in Xubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, launcher, chromium, user-profile

What is the command to add into a Xfce launcher that would start a specific Chromium profile?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the profile to use from the command line with the `--profile-directory` option:

```
chromium-browser --profile-directory="Profile 1"
chromium-browser --profile-directory="Default"
```

To know the list of available profiles look into `~/.config/chromium`:

```
$ ls ~/.config/chromium
./                            Profile 1/
../                           Safe Browsing Bloom
Certificate Revocation Lists  Safe Browsing Bloom Prefix Set
Channels                      Safe Browsing Cookies
chrome_shutdown_ms.txt        Safe Browsing Cookies-journal
Crash Reports/                Safe Browsing Csd Whitelist
Default/                      Safe Browsing Download
First Run                     Safe Browsing Download Whitelist
Local State                   Safe Browsing Extension Blacklist
pnacl/                        Safe Browsing IP Blacklist
```

Source: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: works fine with Xfce launchers